# Los datos de un select deben depender de lo que seleccione en otro, Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

Estoy utilizando consultas a través de una base de datos MySQL en mis 2 select, pero lo que quiero es que al seleccionar un dato en el primer select, el segundo select solo me muestre los datos que se relacionen al que seleccioné en el primero.

> register.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-auto mt-4">
    <label class="mr-4">País<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <select type="text" class="form-control" name="paises" required>
        <option disabled>-Seleccione un país-</option>
        <option *ngFor="let pais of paises">{{pais.id}}. {{pais.pais}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-auto mt-4">
    <label class="mr-4">Estado<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <select type="text" class="form-control" required>
        <option disabled>-Seleccione un estado-</option>
        <option *ngFor="let estado of estados">{{estado.id}}. {{estado.estado}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Siendo más específico, la tabla estados de mi base tiene como foranea el id de la tabla paises, al seleccionar en el select países "México", me aparezcan en el select estados solo los que tienen como foranea el id de México.

> register.component.ts

```
 constructor(private lugaresService: LugaresService) { }

 paises: any = [];
 estados: any = [];

 ngOnInit() {
   this.lugaresService.getPaises().subscribe(
     res => {
       this.paises = res;
     },
     err => console.error(err)
   );
   this.lugaresService.getEstados().subscribe(
     res => {
       this.estados = res;
     },
     err => console.error(err)
   );
 }
```

> lugares.service.ts

```
API_URI = 'http://localhost:3000/api';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

//Paises
getPaises() {
  return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/paises`);
}

getPais(id: string) {
  return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/paises/${id}`);
}

//Estados
getEstados() {
  return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/estados`);
}

getEstado(id: string) {
  return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/estados/${id}`);
}
```

**PUSE LO QUE ES RELEVANTE DE CADA ARCHIVO, SI FALTA ALGO FAVOR DE AVISARME**

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar la propiedad "change" del select para cargar los datos de manera dinámica para el segundo select:

```
    <div class="col-md-auto mt-4">
      <label class="mr-4">País<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <select type="text" class="form-control" name="paises" (change)="loadEstados(formulario.pais.id)" [(ngModel)]="formulario.pais" required>
        <option disabled>-Seleccione un país-</option>
        <option *ngFor="let pais of paises">{{pais.id}}. {{pais.pais}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-auto mt-4" *ngIf="estados">
      <label class="mr-4">Estado<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <select type="text" class="form-control" required>
        <option disabled>-Seleccione un estado-</option>
        <option *ngFor="let estado of estados">{{estado.id}}. {{estado.estado}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  loadEstados(pais_id: string) {
    // Carga aquí tus estados desde tu base de datos con un servicio
    this.estados = await this.servicio.loadEstadosByPais(pais_id);
  }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué pusiste en el change y en ngModule "formulario? Disculpa mi ignorancia, es que soy principiante aun.